# How can I say "belong (somewhere)"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that *aparteni al* means *to belong to*. What about *to belong somewhere*?

- He belongs on the contryside.
- No, you can not bring the snail home. It belongs in the forrest, honey.
- This poem is about the sense of belonging.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that "to belong somewhere" is just a more poetic way of saying "something belongs to a place" with a bit of the ownership sense of the word being justified.

- Li apartenas al la kamparo.
- Ne, vi ne rajtas kunporti la limakon hejmen. Ĝi estas apartena al la arbaro, kara.
- Ĉi tiu poemo estas pri la senco de aparteneco.

However, the affix "-ind-" has a sense of what "should be". So maybe "lokindi" could mean to belong in a place. I made it up, but it should be understandable.

- Li lokindas al la kamparo.
- Ne, vi ne rajtas bringi la limakon hejmen. Ĝi estas lokinda al la arbaro, kara.
- Ĉi tiu poemo estas pri la senco de lokindeco.

But I'm not sure "lokindi" provides any more meaning than "aperteni".

Comment: "bringi"? I think the word you're looking for is "(kun)porti"

Comment: The first part is clever, I din't think of that. I have some doubts about the second idea, but I really enjoy hearing proposals for creative use of the affixes. Alsways interesting. Now, I think senco actually doesn't fit in there, going by the definition in PIV, but I also doesn't know what to replace it with. (maybe that can make another question) I'm being very picky, it's just a detail.

Comment: @kristan Yes, you're right. I've fixed it. One problem with so many English import words is that it becomes hard to remember which words _do not_ import.

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro I wasn't sure about the exact meaning you were going for with "sense of belonging." I went with "The poem is about the meaning of belonging," but it could also be "... the feeling of belonging", or even "... about how one senses that they belong."

Comment: @Ah... I see! I was thinking of one of the two last ones.